# Wrong Library Imported via #pragma comment(lib, ...) in Visual C++

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, dllimport

I'm using Visual Studio 2008.  I have a DLL and a test program EXE.  There is a header file for the DLL that contains this:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
    #pragma comment(lib, "FooD.lib")
#else
    #pragma comment(lib, "Foo.lib")
#endif
```

The intent is to dynamically link to FooD.dll through the FooD.lib import library, for a debug build, and to Foo.dll for a release build.  The problem is that when I run the debug-build test program, it wants to be linked to Foo.dll.

I have verified that `_DEBUG` is defined for the test program in a debug build.  If I replace the `#pragma comment` with an `#error` directive, I see the error, so I'm pretty sure that the `#pragma comment` is being processed as I expect.

I have also verified that both `FooD.dll` and `FooD.lib` exist.  (`Foo.dll` and `Foo.lib` do not exist.)  But at runtime, I get a "Cannot find Foo.dll" error message.

Any idea what might be going wrong, or where I can look to figure out why the incorrect DLL is being looked for at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my problem: the `Foo.def` file had this line:

```
LIBRARY "Foo.DLL"
```

This causes the import library to specify `Foo.dll`, regardless of what the actual DLL name is.  So I just commented out that line, and everything worked fine thereafter.